# Casting in python

Tags: python, casting

I have problem with casting in python.

I have a method in file module_A.py:

```
import Common.Models.Pax as Pax

def verify_passangers_data(self,paxes):
    for i in range(len(paxes)):
         pax=paxes[i]
```

Here is my Pax.py

```
class Pax:
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------



class Adult(Pax):

    def __init__(self,last_day_of_travel,first_name,last_name,nationality,address=None):
        self.birth_day=datetime.today() - timedelta(days = random.randrange(6563, 20793-(date.today()-last_day_of_travel).days))
        self.first_name=first_name
        self.last_name=last_name
        self.nationality=nationality
        self.address=address
```

This is how I create collection in another module(module_C.py):

```
paxes=[]
        paxes.append(Pax.Adult(last_day_of_travel,'FirstName','LastName',Nationality.Poland,DataRepository.addresses['Default']))
```

but, look at my output from debug probe (in wing ide)

```
>>> type(pax)
<class 'Common.Models.Pax.Adult'>
>>> pax is Common.Models.Pax.Adult
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
builtins.NameError: name 'Common' is not defined
```

How can I check is pax is instance of Adult?

Comment: Don't see how this has anything to do with casting.

Comment: `NameError: name 'Common' is not defined` means that you didnt import `Common` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I check is pax is instance of Adult?

Use the `isinstance` function:

```
isinstance(pax, Common.Models.Pax.Adult)
```

Make you have imported the class, though (e.g., `import Common.Models.Pax`).

(Although purists would argue that there's rarely a need to check the type of a Python object. Python is dynamically typed, so you should generally check to see if an object responds to a particular method call, rather than checking its type. But you may have a good reason for needing to check the type, too.)

Comment: """ so you should generally check to see if an object responds to a particular method call, rather than checking its type""" - very wild claim

Comment: @RestRisiko: No, it's exactly what duck typing is about. Nobody cares if these `widgets` are instances of `FooDialog` if you just want to `.hide()` them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isinstance`:

```
isinstance(pax, Common.Models.Pax.Adult)
```

Or the builtin `type` function:

```
type(pax) == Common.Models.Pax.Adult
```

Of course, you will have to import the module so that `Common.Models.Pax.Adult` is defined. That's why you're getting that error at the end.

Comment: Note that if B is a subclass of A, and `b = B()`, then `isinstance(b, A)` will be True, while `type(b) == A` will be False.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have imported the type in order to reference it:

```
>>> x is socket._fileobject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'socket' is not defined
>>> import socket
>>> x is socket._fileobject
False
```

Presumably, you obtained the instance pointed to by `pax` from some other call, so you haven't actually imported the class into your namespace.

Also, `is` tests object identity (are these the same object?), not type.  You want `instanceof(pax,Common...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors, first one is using `is` instead of `isinstance` function. Second is trying to refer module by it's absolute name, but you've imported it with alias.

Thus what you should do is:

```
isinstance(pax,Pax.Adult)
```